# Side Menu Collapsed by Befault in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have searched the web for an answer and I can't find it.

Using bootstrap, what do I do to have a side menu collapsed by default?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Side Menu. Can you provide your markup?

Comment: Please provide more detail and/or some relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you a referring to this [pre-canned sidebar](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/simple-sidebar/).

In which case you need to add the CSS class `toggled` to your `#wrapper` div like so:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="toggled">
  ...
</div>
```

Also please give sample code with such specific questions or you will get down voted and the question will probably be flagged. SO isn't that volatile an environment but if you want a good answer you need to post a good question. That includes doing your research, creating a JSFiddle, explaining what you have tried thus far etc.